# Filed calculator python code for auto increment not working

Tags: arcpy, field-calculator

I have a bit of python code for the field calculator for numbering records from a given number by a given interval. It works most of the time, but sometimes it'll number out of order. It will use the right interval and end at the expected number, but not in the order I want. I've checked if the FID and ObjectID are all in numerical order, which they are. The only thing I can think of that may be causing an issue is that the field is a Text field. I've posted the little code snip below.

```
rec=0
def autoIncrement():
 global rec
 pStart = 1 
 pInterval = 1 
 if (rec == 0): 
  rec = pStart 
 else: 
  rec = rec + pInterval 
 return rec
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have answered your own question really, this code is returning integers and ArcMap is casting them into string fields, hence the out of sequence you are experiencing.

Run this code on a numeric field instead.

Comment: Okay, I was pretty sure that was causing the issue. Is there any way I could make it work for a string field? Unfortunately it has to remain a string field.

Comment: Could try running the code on a numeric field, create a string field, copy them in and delete the numeric field? Don't know if that solves it? Or try the suggestions above?

Comment: I think I might just have to do it that way. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ive had the same problem its a field type issue.Run the code on a numeric field, or change it to:

```
rec=0
def autoIncrement():
 global rec
 pStart = 1 
 pInterval = 1 
 if (rec == 0): 
  rec = pStart 
 else: 
  rec = rec + pInterval 
 return str(rec)
```

To convert the value to a string.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like an issue with ArcGIS not reading the attribute table in the order of the OID field, which I've heard of happening before. My first suggestion is to copy/paste the feature class, delete the old, and try your code on the new. If this isn't a possibility or if it doesn't solve the problem I'd create a dictionary from a search cursor that's been sorted by your OID field.

Something like this in your code block:

```
layer = r"yourlayername"

rec=0
def autoIncrement():
 global rec
 pStart = 1 
 pInterval = 1 
 if (rec == 0): 
  rec = pStart 
 else: 
  rec = rec + pInterval 
 return rec

#empty dictionary
di = {}
#get oid field
oidFld = arcpy.Describe (layer).OIDFieldName
#where clause to order by oid field
clause = (None, "ORDER BY {}".format (oidFld))
#search cursor - read table sorted by oid
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor (layer, "OID@", sql_clause = clause) as curs:
    #iterate
    for oid, in curs:
        #update dictionary with oid and auto increment number
        di [oid] = autoIncrement ()

#now you can use a simple function to return increment
def returnVal (OID):
    return di [OID]
```

Then use `returnVal (!*OBJECTIDFIELDNAME*!)` for your field calculator.

[image]